# Rewrite rule for search page using opencart

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart2.x

I want to change product/search page URL using opencart

`My URL : index.php?route=product/search&search=test_name`

I want to URL like `search_product/test_name`

HTTACCESS file code:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myshop
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule    ^search_product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?route=product/search&search=$1    [NC,L]  #search page
</IfModule>`

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780840/htaccess-mod-rewrite-for-opencart-search-page-urls. May be it helps

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't not work.

Comment: what is not working, please be spacific..

Comment: I add this code for search page  `RewriteRule    ^search_product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?route=product/search&search=$1    [NC,L]  #search page`  but it doesn't rewrite url.